# Using a formula with a sheet name specified in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I searched a lot, and now I will explain this as best I can:

I have a lot of sheets. In the first one (but only for example) I will have in A1 a list which contains the list of exact sheet names.

And in A2 I want to use the sheet named in A1 like this:

> ='A1'!C5

That for me would mean: Cell A2 is equal to the cell C5 contained in the sheet named in A1. Can this be done? Thanks so much for help!

(p.s. I would like not to use VBA)

Riccardo

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!C5")` or little more sophisticated: `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!" & CELL("address",C5))`?

Comment: Is a string list, nothing strange, let's imagine there is a default text, but is a data validation list.
@simoco I will try soon, dinner then i will try. 
Thanks both for helps.

Comment: Karl Rookey, thanks for grammar corrections, I'm sorry for my low english!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you can use next formulas.

1. "Static" version  - after dragging formula down or accross, it still refers to `C5`

   ```
   =INDIRECT("'" & $A$1 & "'!C5")
   ```
2. "Draggable" version (you can use it in `A2` and then, say, drag to `B2` and Excel automatically adjust `C5` to `D5`):

   ```
   =INDIRECT("'" & $A$1 & "'!" & CELL("address",C5))
   ```

Comment: Very tricking to use (adding that I had to use a range, but it works very well).
Thanks, it works, it is what I was searching. Can you explain me this please!? I really don't take something ("'" for example).
Thanks a lot again!

Comment: sure, __1)__ if sheet name contains spaces we should use single quotes in formula like this: `='my sheet'!C5`. I.e. if `A1` contains `my sheet`, then  `"'" & $A$1 & "'!"` returns `'my sheet'!`. __2)__ `INDIRECT` just takes _text_ and converts it to reference. You can read more here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx __3)__ in `CELL("address",C5)` a little bit tricky, it converts reference `C5` to text `"C5"`. I didn't like hardcode address like in first formula, because in that case formula is not draggable (if you drag it, formula still refers to `C5`)

Comment: thanks again! I will make a new question with a similar argument, but in vba and with other type. I'm pretty sure you can answer to that too anche i'm pretty sure that indirect maybe an answer, but can't make it works.) Thanks again!